# User interaction disabled on main view as long as modal window is open (Xcode/iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, presentmodalviewcontroller

I open a modal window from my AppDelegate (actually called from another ViewController, not the best way..):

```
UIBlurEffect * blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];
UIVisualEffectView *myView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
myView.frame = self.main.view.bounds;
myModalWindow.view.frame = self.main.view.bounds;
myModalWindow.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[myModalWindow.view insertSubview:myView atIndex:0];
myModalWindow.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

[self.main presentViewController:myModalWindow animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The i try to minimize that window to attach to the bottom of the screen (from within the modal):

```
- (void)minimizeToBottom {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:ViewFadeInOutTime animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - self.menuBar.frame.size.height;
        self.view.frame = frame;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

But when I do this, the view in the background can't receive any touches/interaction. How do I still interact with my main view, while having the modal staying at the bottom of the screen. Just like "Spotify's small player" and others.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT - **SOLVED!**

Changed from modal to view and then I was doing

```
[self.window addSubview: myWindow.view];
```

But I changed that to

```
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview: myWindow.view];
```

Comment: Add the UIView with the desired frame as subview to your active UIViewController, no need to use a modalViewController

Comment: "modal" means "only I get input" As long as your modal is visible, other views can't get input.

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks for support.
Did [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview: myWindow.view];
because I was doing [self.window addSubview: myWindow.view];